# Add timer to list object

Tags: c#

Is there a simple way to add, let's say **DispatcherTimer()** or any kind of timer to a **List** when I add that object?

So the added object could track its time and get deleted after some time? Maybe with a Event or simply an Action.

Cause adding a time to every object and iterating through all objects inside List doesn't seem to be clean and efficient.

Comment: No, but you can directly use MemoryCache instead of building one.

Comment: MemoryCache will not track items in list individually.
If I am not getting wrong @myrez would want object to expire and removed from the list also.In my opinion some sort of Queuing mechanism like RabbitMQ or MSMQ with a expiry time on message would be a good fit.

Comment: The right way to do this, as you seem to have heard, is to use expiration, not timers, i.e. "adding a time to every object." That is far cleaner and more efficient than creating a bunch of timers and threads and potential concurrency issues. What would happen if you were iterating over the list when one of the timers goes off?